# Use javascript code inside php

Tags: javascript, php

My question is quite simple, but it is bit hard for me to use javascript inside php code.

Here is my code:

```
<script>var showdiv1  = 0;</script>     
--- some html codes ---------   
<script>showdiv1 = showdiv1 + 1;</script>               
<div class="col-md-12 box" id= "div<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>showdiv1</script>"?>"><br />
```

I am getting output.

```
<div id="div<script type='text/javascript'>showdiv1</script>" class="col-md-12 box">
```

Expected output:

```
<div id="div1" class="col-md-12 box">
```

Please advise, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: you can't use the client side script to a server side script like this.

Comment: PHP is executed on the server, before it is sent to the browser. Javascript is executed when the browser renders the page. You cannot use them as if they are executed at the same time, because they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript and PHP are two separated things, while JS runs in the client, PHP will run in the server.
So:

```
<script>var showdiv1  = 0;</script>     
--- some html codes ---------   
<script>showdiv1 = showdiv1 + 1;</script>
```

Will create a JS variable with value of 1. PHP have no idea of this variable so cant be used there.

The line `<div class="col-md-12 box" id= "div<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>showdiv1</script>"?>"><br />` behave as expected, printing  `<div id="div<script type='text/javascript'>showdiv1</script>" class="col-md-12 box">`

Maybe what you are trying to accomplish is:

```
<?php $showdiv1  = 0; ?>     
--- some html codes ---------   
<?php $showdiv1 = $showdiv1 + 1; ?>               
<div class="col-md-12 box" id= "div<?php echo $showdiv1 ?>"><br />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.

Answer (score 2):

php is a server side script and Javascript  is Client Side.
you can use javascript in php statement as string but its important to khnow  that javascript code only run web page loded on browser.

there is alternative solution for your problem.
1. create your tag id  with php variables and sent it to your javascript like this:

```
<script>
var x=<?= $mydivId; ?>;
</script>
```

2. user jquery to create dynamic tag on client side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.